# SSRS 2008: Expression to determine width of bar in chart?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2008

I have a query which returns a dataset like the one below:

```
WaitTimeGroup   WaitTimeGroupID     WaitTimeGroupNotify    Count
upto 1h         1                   0                      0
upto 2h         2                   0                      5
upto 3h         3                   0                      15
upto 3h30m      4                   1                      3
upto 3h45m      5                   2                      2
upto 4h         6                   3                      1
upto 6h         7                   0                      9
upto 12h        8                   0                      0
over 12h        9                   0                      0
```

Which is then used to display the following chart using SSRS 2008:

[image]

What I would like to be able to do is make the non-gray bars wider, in particular the bright red one. The colors are determined by the WaitTimeGroupNotify value.

I've tried setting an expression in the PixelPointWidth CustomAttribute property though this displayed all bars with the same width.

Is this possible using SSRS 2008 or perhaps someway it can be achieved by modifying my dataset?

Answer (score 0):

Try to set the width (`CustomAttributes -> PointWidth`) dynamically using expression, something similar to the following :

```
= IIF(CInt(Fields!WaitTimeGroupNotify.Value)=3,.2,1.98)
```

... you need to experiment to reach for the desired PointWidth value.